# Can't install Visio 2016, "the following products can not be installed at the same time"

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio-2016

I'm trying to install visio 2016 (licence for 5 installs, but only 3 have been used so far) on a office PC but when I do I get this error message:

[image: "the following products can not be installed at the same time"]

I thought I this was because office 2010 was installed on the PC, but when I uninstalled that I still get the error.  Also there was a trial of office 2016 on the PC that was uninstalled, and I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

[image: programs and features control panel]

Comment: Is this a volume license edition of Visio?

Comment: yes 5 licenses, but it doesn't even get that far to enter the licence and soon as the installer starts up , i get that message

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the fact you're installing a volume license version.

Comment: Wait a second, "licensed for 5 installs" is not necessarily a volume license install. Do you know if yours is volume license or not?

Comment: "Here is your VISIO 5 PC license key........You can download 32-bit / 64-bit MS Visio / Project 2016 Pro from the link below:
www.office.com/setup
"  Thats all the info I have, no mention of "volume license"

Comment: That's not volume license. That is a Click-to-Run installation. Which means you still have an MSI-based installation of an Office application on your computer. What else is shown in Add/Remove programs in Control Panel that's Office related?

Comment: that screenshot ( 2nd one) is everything that is microsoft as the publisher.  Could some 3rd party office plugin be causing this?

Comment: No, but an incomplete installation of an MSI-based installation of Office would.

Comment: A log file should have been generated.  Please provide the relevant information from that log file.

Comment: where would the log file be? in the event viewer? do see anything there

Comment: 'To find out whether your installation is MSI or C2R, in the Microsoft Office application, such as Word or Excel, go to File > Account. If you see an Office Updates section, the installation is C2R <snip> If there is no Office Updates section, then it is an MSI installation'  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2016/06/23/determining-your-office-version-msi-vs-c2r/

Comment: K7AAY: Office has been uninstalled so I don't have a option to do this.

Comment: @PaddyD Based on the error window, it seems that there is other Visio product existed on current computer which is conflict with this installing one. I suggest you can use the following script to check current Office version: Run as Administrator to open cmd, type 
cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office16\"ospp.vbs /dstatus

If you are running 32-bit Office 2016 on a 64-bit operating system, the script is: 
cscript.exe "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office16\"ospp.vbs /dstatus

Comment: @WinniL I tried both command and file can not be found, and if look up the office folders (in explorer) they are empty

Comment: If there is no folder, maybe there is no Office 2016 product installed on your computer. I suggest you can follow the manually uninstall Office article to check the registry for Office, remove all related keys to reinstall Visio 2016: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manually-uninstall-office-4e2904ea-25c8-4544-99ee-17696bb3027b

Comment: I did a factory reset on the pc and it turns out it has a trial version of office 2013 baked in with it.  I uninstalled it and then tried the manual uninstall it but I could not find any office files related to it.  Yet I still get the error when I try to install visio 2016.  I'm at a loss

Answer (score 0):

You probably have remnants of the Office 2016 Click to Run installation which is [conflicting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/install-different-office-visio-and-project-versions-on-the-same-computer) with your volume-license MSI installer. Since you've already tried uninstalling Office from the Control Panel, the next step is to download and run Microsoft's click to run un-installer tool. It's available [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8).

This will remove everything from the previous click to run installation that's blocking your MSI-based installation.

Comment: funny enough that's what i'm in the middle of doing now, will let you know if that works

Comment: no luck, still getting the same message  after using the easy fix tool